# How can i generate dynamic sequence number of transaction controller

Tags: jmeter

**Usecase :-** I have one thread group. Inside this i have one loop controller. In loop controller i have 120 transaction controller. During debugging of the script it creates confusion to find the failed steps. I want to put some variable for dynamic number generation. I did it by using Beanshell Sampler as following:

[image]

After this i used beanshell function **${__BeanShell(Integer.parseInt(vars.get("POC_Step_Number"))+1,POC_Step_Number)}** inside the name of transaction controller. It works for me.
[image]

I want to use variable name in place of Beanshell function **${__BeanShell(Integer.parseInt(vars.get("POC_Step_Number"))+1,POC_Step_Number)}** function. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [loop controller index](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) (add +1 if you want to start with 1)

```
${__groovy(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx}+1)}
```

> JMeter will expose the looping index as a variable named **jm**__idx. So for example, if your Loop Controller is named LC, then you can access the looping index through `${__jm__LC__idx}`. Index starts at 0